# Debug Log of deployment test execution

Tags: deployment, debugging, logging

Is it possible to see debug logs from Deployment Tests?  I'm having some test's fail and it would be very helpful to see the logs.

Comment: one workaround - deploy to fullcopy sandbox and then run the failing tests w debug log there

Comment: Yes, if you have dev console open while you are deploying..Although you may run into truncation issues due to size

Comment: @crop1645 unfortunately the test aren't failing in full copy :/

Comment: @Eric are you sure?  I already tried that and nothing came up on the logs.

Comment: @NSjonas - It does for me, but then I am using change sets as well. If a test fails I can see it in the logs. Then again, the dev console is so buggy....At least they used to.....

Comment: so Fullcopy is a current refresh of PROD, you deployed to fullcopy and then explicitly ran the tests that were failing in the PROD deploy in fullcopy?  (deploying to fullcopy doesn't automatically run any tests)

Comment: Hmm, I'll try again.  I'm using the new "Selective Test" validation feature so hopefully the log won't be truncated.

Comment: @crop1645 No, but refreshing isn't an option.  This is a large org and it takes over a week to refresh.  Not to mention, there are other teams with WIP.

Comment: @Eric Nice, yea I guess the console had just bonked out on me before.  Worked this time!

Comment: @NSjonas - Sweet posting it as an answer although it feels a little light. Feel free to add to it (specific steps you took)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you have dev console open while you are deploying.  With Change Sets, you can avoid log truncation by running specified tests.

[image]